# java.io.IOException Android

Tags: android, inputstream

Trying to download a large file on Android 2.3.5 on a HTC explorer. I keep getting the exception java.io.IOException at this point  :

while ((oneChar = is.read()) != -1)

FYI is - InputStream. 
It throws java.io.IOException : unexpected end of stream.

It does not happen all the time but happens frequently enough. I tried searching for this and found out that apparently there is a bug in Android 2.3.3 relating to this but my question is then how is everybody else able to download stuff on Android 2.3.3 if such a bug exists ?
I have seen solutions where all data is first written to a buffer and then entire stuff is written to a file but I can't do that too since the file size is going to be large and it will exceed the max heap size in Android which is around 16MB. I have tried downloading this same file using a fixed buffer size as well and even that version throws an exception. Any solutions ? I am really stuck. In fact a work around was proposed on the google website but even that failed when I tried. Source : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14562

Comment: Could you provide more code so that we have some context? The Logcat output for your error would be helpful as well.